# Can We Transform a System of n First order linear ODE's into an nth order linear ODE?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I already know that if we have the following linear ODE $$y^{(n)} -f(x,y,y',...,y^{(n-1)}) = 0$$ with initial conditions $y(t_0) = a_0, y'(t_0) = a_1, ...,y^{(n-1)} = a_{n-1}, $ we can transform this ODE into a system of linear first order system of n ODE's. $$y_{1}' = y_{2},$$
$$y_{2}' = y_{3},$$ $$y_{3}' = y_{4}, ..., $$ and $$y_{n}' =f(t,y_1,y_2,...,y_n). $$ with initial conditions $y_1(t_0) = a_0, y_2(t_0) = a_1, ...,y_n(t_0) = a_{n-1}. $ My question is is it true if we have a system of n first order linear ODE's, can we express it as an nth order linear ODE? If so, how can we find it? I was thinking about expressing this in a matrix ODE and finding the answer there but I don't know if it's the way to go. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. Consider the system
$$
\dot x= x,\quad \dot y=y.
$$
Obviously, this system can't be transformed to an ODE.

This example may seem trivial, but one can do some tricky change of variables and obtain some complicated system which is also not equivalent to an ODE.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your example right (I am a beginner in ODEs). I assume that we can't transform your system into a second order ODE simply because both first order ODEs don't depend on each other. Right?

Comment: @Philipp Yes. A second order ode is actually a special case of a system of two equations. The second order ode/system variables (let's call them $z$ and $\dot z$) are depend on each other($\dot z$ is a derivative of $z$), but $x$ and $y$ in this example are totally independent. Therefore, there can not exist a change of variables/diffeomorphism between $x$, $y$  and hypothetically existing $z$ and $\dot z$.